# Water Level Indicator - Rasp Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, gpio

Im creating a project which is water level indicator with raspberry pi. So when i put the wires in water, the led will automatically light on.

My question is i want to make the first LED turned off when the 2nd wire touches the water.

This is the sample picture:

[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgA6r.jpg)

Here is my sample code

```
 while True:
   GPIO.output(led8output, 0)
   GPIO.output(led10output, 0)

   if GPIO.input(led8input) == 1:
     GPIO.output(led8output, 1)

   if GPIO.input(led10input) == 1:
     GPIO.output(led10output, 1)
     GPIO.output(led8output, 0)   #this code wont make the first led turn off.
```

I've even tried elif and if(GPIO.input(led10input) == 1 and GPIO.input(led8input) ==1) both doesnt work. Please help. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better placed on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not quite sure this is a good fit for SO. However - your first step should be to see if `GPIO.output(led8output, 0)` in isolation (outside of the `if`) actually turns off the LED, then to check that when the 2nd wire is put in the water `GPIO.input(led10input) == 1` actually is true. One of these will be the cause - we have no way of knowing which one.

Comment: I also tried to make the 2 leds off. I forgot to add this line. But it also doesnt work.

Comment: @KlausD. Sir sorry but rasppi.stackexchange doesnt have many people so i posted it here. Just RESPECT my post. Thank you.

Comment: Hello there...

Did my code help you?

If so please choose it as anwer / upvote it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
GPIO.output(led8output, 0)
GPIO.output(led10output, 0)

 while True:
   if GPIO.input(led8input) == 1 and GPIO.input(led10input) == 0:
     print "1st led has been turned on"
     GPIO.output(led8output, 1)

   if GPIO.input(led10input) == 1 and GPIO.input(led8input) == 1:
     print "Both leds have been turned on therefore turning 1st led off"
     GPIO.output(led10output, 1)
     GPIO.output(led8output, 0)
```